# How to use Azure DevOps artifacts for upstream power-shell modules from https://powershellgallery.com

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, feed, powershell-module

Is there a way for using Azure DevOps artifacts and upstream power shell modules.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for using Azure DevOps artifacts and upstream power shell modules.

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I am afraid we could not add the power shell modules as upstream sources at this moment.

According to the document [Configure upstream sources for Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/how-to/set-up-upstream-sources?view=azure-devops), we could to know:

> Custom upstream sources are only available for **npm.**

[image]

Besides, there is a suggestion ticket about this request on our main forum for product suggestions:

[Allow PowerShell Gallery to be added as a public upstream source](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/598437/allow-powershell-gallery-to-be-added-as-a-public-u.html)

You could vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Hope this helps.